# in react native I want to execute a method in component after doing poptoTop

Tags: react-native

I have a navigator that shows a dashboard

```
<Navigator
  ref="nav"
  navigationBarHidden={true}
  style={styles.container}
  initialRoute={{name: 'dashboard'}}
  renderScene={this.renderScene}
  configureScene={() => { returnNavigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }}
/>
```

I am able to increment and decrement a counter in a basket on this page for buying products, after i have completed buying the products i use

```
this.props.navigator.popToTop()
```

to go back, unfortunately the counter is still the same, how can i call a method in dashboard when i go back to it to reset the counter in the basket or how can i call componentDidMount again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another [lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods), for example `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillUpdate`. If this fixes you bug is hard to say, as you haven't provided enough code to understand what is happening in your App.